# DSE 5.1 CASSANDRA 5.11 NOT ABLE TO CREATE roles for internal mode

Tags: authentication, cassandra, role

I have 1 node cassandra cluster. What I need is to create a user and addsome roles to it. I have done the following datastax example:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE warehouse WITH REPLICATION = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 
'replication_factor':1};

USE warehouse;

CREATE TABLE addresses (
customer_id bigint,
address_id int,
address text,
PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, address_id)
);

CREATE ROLE supervisor;
GRANT SELECT ON warehouse.addresses TO supervisor;
CREATE ROLE pam WITH PASSWORD = 'password' AND LOGIN = true;
GRANT supervisor TO pam;
```

So user Pam is only able to read from warehouse.addresses. However, when I login with pam and select data from a keyspace1.table different from warehouse.addresses, the data is served:

```
cqlsh xxx.x.xx.xx -u pam -p password
pam@cqlsh> select from keyspace1.table 1 where id= 1
```

Pam is able to do everything in every keyspace, she is acting as a superuser and I do not understand why. When I list all roles and permissions of pam, everything is correct, superuser is false.

What I have changed in dse.yaml is:

```
authentication_options:
   enabled: true
   default_scheme: internal
   allow_digest_with_kerberos: false
   plain_text_without_ssl: warn
   transitional_mode: disabled
   other_schemes:
   scheme_permissions: false

role_management_options:
   mode: internal

authorization_options:
   enabled: true
   transitional_mode: normal
   allow_row_level_security: true
```

cassandra.yaml:

```
authenticator: com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator
authorizer: com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthorizer
role_manager: com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseRoleManager
```

Answer (score 1):

After you updated the yaml files did you restart DSE?

Comment: Yes. Firstly I updated the yaml file, then restart dse service and after that create the roles

Answer (score 0):

Configure the transitional_mode to 'strict' in both authentication_options and authorization_options in dse.yaml and perform a restart of your nodes